# Slang term for leaving the criminal world?

Tags: slang

Is there a more up-to-date slang term for **leaving the criminal world** than "to be out of the business" or "to go respectable"?

Answer (score 3):

As Xanne said ["go straight"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20straight) is a common informal phrase

> to stop being a criminal

Another slang phrase is ["go legit"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+legit)

> To begin behaving honestly after previous involvement with nefarious or illegal activities.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/go-straight) also gives the following synonyms:

- reform
- get back on the straight and narrow